# List emails in an Office 365 mailbox using Powershell

Tags: powershell

In the Powershell script below I need to see the inbox/messages in the shared mailbox `mobileprint@abcdef.com`. But the script returns the inbox/messages in the admin account - `admin@abcdef.com`.
The admin account has access to the shared mailbox and should be providing the script the credentials to access the sharedmailbox.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.0\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll")
$s = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService
$AdminName = "admin@abcdef.com"
$Pass = Get-Content "cred_.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$s.Credentials = New-Object Net.NetworkCredential($AdminName , $Pass)
$s.AutodiscoverUrl("mobileprint@abcdef.com", {$true})
$inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($s,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)
$inbox
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Henrik. I finally got it. I had to use the Impersonation lines to get it to work. This helped [Using EWS impersonation and PowerShell to log into an Exchange Online Mailbox](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/circularlogging/2015/02/10/using-ews-impersonation-and-powershell-to-log-into-an-exchange-online-mailbox/)

```js
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.0\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll")
$s = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService
$Mailbox = "mobileprint@abcdef.com"
$AdminName = "admin@abcdef.com"
$Pass = Get-Content "cred_.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$s.Credentials = New-Object Net.NetworkCredential($AdminName , $Pass)
$s.AutodiscoverUrl($AdminName, {$true})
$s.ImpersonatedUserId = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress,$Mailbox )
$InboxFolder= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$ImpersonatedMailboxName)
$Inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($s,$InboxFolder)
$inbox
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you check out https://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2016/10/ews-basics-accessing-and-using-shared.html

It has some really good explanations in regards to using EWS to access folders.

The part that is interesting to you is properly this bit here:

To Access a Mailbox folder in EWS you need to know the EWSId of the folder, the one exception to this rule are the WellKnownFolders like the Inbox,Contacts,Calendar etc. With these WellKnowFolders you can tell EWS which folder you want in which mailbox without knowing the EWSId of that folder.

Eg to Access the Inbox in a Shared Mailbox you use the FolderId overload to define the folderId you want to access and then bind to that folder:

> $folderid= new-objectMicrosoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId ([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxName)
>
> $Inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)